# Was bedeutet "Bussi schleck"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean in German when someone says

> Bussi schleck

? I can't find any reference.

The context is as follows: my team leader (a woman from Bavaria) proposed it as a name for our team:) I am afraid it might be a little bit obscene or perverse :D

Comment: Did you really hear that or did you see it in a forum or something?

Comment: The context where you heard it could be helpful.

Comment: Yes, context please. Especially as we have two *very different* competing answers that can easily be disambiguated by context, by spelling (if you've seen it written) or by geography (if you know where the speaker was from).

Comment: I don't know the purpose of the team, but if it's business related, and  "Bussy schleck" is her proposal, i'm not sure if she's the right person for leadership.

Answer (score 13):

"Bussi" (das) means (short, non-French) "kiss".

"schlecken" means "to lick", and "schleck" is the Mickey-Mouse-style* shortened form of it.

The word "Bussi" is used primarily in Austria and Bavaria, I have no idea how much it extends northward.
"Bussi" is sometimes also used as a relatively intimate greeting; among close family members, among lovers. It is not considered obscene.

"Bussi schleck" is not a set phrase, but I can perfectly imagine a pair of lovers making it up as a slightly erotic private greeting. The reference to licking makes it slightly obscene; it would be OK for friends of the couple to overhear it, but the couple should not use it in "polite society".

---

* yes, really: this grammatical form in the German language was essentially made up to translate things like "*sigh*" in Mickey Mouse comics to "*seufz*"); this form is also called "Inflektiv" or "Erikativ" after its inventor, Erika Fuchs.

Comment: wow, didn't know about [Inflektiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv)!

Answer (score 8):

I assume it is a shortened form of the label

> Bussy Mix - 10 Schleckdrinks

as it might appear on receipts or price tags.

"Bussy" is a brand name, owned by the company [Busemann GmbH](http://www.busemann-gmbh.de/home/). They manufacture popcorn and ice pops.

"schlecken" means "to lick" or "to lap up" and "Schleckdrink" (approximately "licking drink") is the product name of their ice pops.

Comment: Someone actually asked for that here http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-ist-ein-bussy-schleck-drink :)

Answer (score -1):

As a two language word play it can be quite "dirty" in the erotic sense, since "Bussi" sounds suspiciously close to a vulgar expression for the vagina. The "u" in "Bussi" is pronounced like the "oo" in "mood", only shorter. A "Bussi" is a non-erotic kiss though, which could be to a child or on the cheek.
"Schleck" refers to licking.
So to perceive the world play in this sense you have to understand both languages.

Comment: Now that's entirely off. https://www.amazon.de/Bussy-Mix-Schleck-Drinks-200er/dp/B0066HHJVE - It's hard to imagine Kid's drinks' names contain vulgar allusions.

Comment: Please note that the German term for a cat is *Muschi*.

Comment: @CarstenS: but even in Germany *Pussi leck* would be unambiguously vulgar.

Comment: @CarstenS Actually the term for "cat" is "Katze", but "Muschi" in german is used like "pussy" in english, including the vulgar meaning.

Comment: @tofro The name of the product ist actually Bussi Mix - Schleck-Drinks. So there is a separation between the 2 words in question. CarstenS' comment made me realize, that the number of people understanding of the meaning of "pussy" is actually increasing in Germany. We have a relatively young female comedian who calls her show "Pussy Terror".

Comment: @Javatasse ... which would be an entirely different show when called "Bussi Terror"... That answer is really extremely far-fetched.

Comment: @tofro You are right about "Bussi Terror". The "dirty" kind of interpretation will only become possible, if the associated word has a meaning relating to "pussy". Think of "Bussi Rasur" (Rasur=shave), which wouldn't be understood only as a very well shaved cheek, so you enjoy placing a kiss on it. It plays a role if the use of the expression happens in an english language context though (I assume that an international software development team will communicate in english). So if there is english communication and the word "Bussi" is used, an english mind will jump to the "dirty" interpretation